# Code formatting interface in answers

Tags: support, answers

Are there any plans to improve the interface for including code snippets in answers?

The simple four-space rule to format as code often does not work, and would certainly be improved by a menu button to indent by the required amount, seeing as the actual code-bracket icon doesn't seem to work.

Also I don't understand why the provided functionality as is doesn't format make code appear in the answer-textarea on the fly to give feedback as to whether the code snippets will actually appear as code i.e. have been correctly inputted and tagged/indented etc. Surely that's not much to ask of stackoverflow's programming team?
I think half my time spent answering questions is spent scrolling up and down to check.

Comment: This is not a bug. It's a feature request at best. And not a very well prepared or researched one.

Comment: When/how does the four-space indentation fail? I've found it to work every time.

Comment: Are you aware there is a button in the editor that will automatically indent the text for you?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to work every time. Also the code appearing as code as soon as it is formatted as code would really help avoid the need to scroll up and down to check.

Comment: @Corion Do you still have to indent beforehand? I'll assume it will work without indenting as well, fingers crossed.

Comment: It does work everytime. You must be doing something wrong. What you want is a _"what you see is what you get"_ editor. That's not what we have, so lacking that **can't** be bug.

Comment: Weird. I'm a user on stackoverflow.com , and there I get a "live" preview of the answer with both, code and `> blockquotes` rendered directly. `CTRL+K` indents/outdents the selection four spaces for me, which marks pasted text as code. So I must be doing something differently than you do. This is with the current Chrome if that matters.

Comment: OK, I'll be ultra-cautious as to how the editor performs from now on, I very likely am doing something wrong. And agreed, lack of functionality isn't a bug. I'll be sure to report back here on exactly how I find the Ctrl+K, or icon interface works.

Comment: Seems to be working now, thanks

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to use a code lock in a bullet or numbered list? Then you need to indent with 8 spaces, or 12 or 16, etc for additional levels of nested lists.

Comment: I don't think anyone else mentioned this, but in case you didn't realize, you need to have a blank line before the code block for the four space indentation to work.

Answer (score 6):

The only way that indentation by four spaces from the UI doesn't work is if you have mixed space types in your code snippet; that is, you're using both tabs *and* spaces.

Overflow-flavored Markdown **only** works with spaces, and if your code is indented with the tab character, it will not automatically translate it over.

Comment: It also doesn't work if the code is in a list item, where 8 spaces are required ...